# $f(x)=3x-\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$, $\quad$ $g(x)=x^3+2x-\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, area, inverse-function

> $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R$ are two functions such that
> $f(x)=3x-\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$, $\quad$ $g(x)=x^3+2x-\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$
> then choose the correct statements

(A) $\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))$ at $x=-12$ is $\frac{2}{3(28+\pi)}$

(B) $\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))$ at $x=-12$ is $\frac{2}{3(28-\pi)}$

(C) Area bounded by $y=f^{-1}(x)$ and $y=g^{-1}(x)$ is $1$

(D) Area bounded by $y=f^{-1}(x)$ and $y=g^{-1}(x)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$

**My Method:**

$(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))=(g(f(x)))^{-1}$

$\implies$

$\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))=\frac{d}{dx}(g(f(x)))^{-1}$

$\implies$

$\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))=\frac{-g'(f(x))f'(x)}{(g(f(x))^{2}}$

But now I'm stuck.

For Option (C)

Because intersection points are $x=-1,x=0,x=1$

So area will be $\int_{-1}^{1}|g(x)-f(x)|dx$

**Solution to Option (A) given in my Solution Image is as follow:**

$\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))=\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}(g(f(x)))_{x=-1}}$

**It seem to me that they must have used $f(g(x))=x$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are Inverse of each other. But I am not sure how did they use in above problem**

Please Help me in this question.

Comment: If $(\beta,\alpha)$ lie on the graph of $f(x)$, then  

$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}\bigg|_{x=\alpha}=\bigg(\frac{df}{dx}\bigg|_{x=\beta}\bigg)^{-1}$$

Comment: How to prove your statement. is it same as $f'(g(x))g'(x)=1$  $\implies$ $f'(g(x))=\frac{1}{g'(x)}$?

Comment: Use $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and chain rule to prove above statement.

Comment: yes that's what I said

Comment: but what is wrong as I did in above post under my method?

Comment: You are using the derivative of the reciprical rule.  Not the derivative of the inverse.  $[g(f(x))]^{-1}$ doe *NOT* mean $\frac 1{g(f(x))}$ so you can not use the rule $[\frac 1{h(x)}]' = -\frac {h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$.  Instead you must use $h(h^{-1}(x)) = x$ so $[h(h^{-1}(x)]' = [x]'$ so $h'(h^{-1}(x))[h^{-1}(x)]=1$ so $[h^{-1}(x)]=\frac 1{h'(h^{-1}(x)}$.  The means $\frac d{dx}(g(f(x))^{-1} =\frac 1{[g'([g\circ f]^{-1}(x))}=\frac 1{g'(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x))}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))=\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}(g(f(x)))_{x=-1}}$$

Let $y=f^{-1}g^{-1}(x).$ Then $$gf(y)=x.$$ Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives
\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(gf(y)\right)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}&=1
\\\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(f^{-1}g^{-1}(x)\right)&=\frac1{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(gf(y)\right)}
\\\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(f^{-1}g^{-1}(x)\right)\bigg|_{x=-12}&=\frac1{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(gf(y)\right)\bigg|_{y=-1}}
\\\ &=\frac1{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(gf(x)\right) \bigg|_{x=-1}}.\end{align}

> **My Method:**
>
> $(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))=(g(f(x)))^{-1}$
>
> $\implies$
>
> $\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))=\frac{d}{dx}(g(f(x)))^{-1}$
>
> $\implies$
>
> $\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)))=\frac{-g'(f(x))f'(x)}{(g(f(x))^{2}}$

1. Your main error was mixing up reciprocal and inverse.
2. A minor secondary issue is the unnecessary use of the $\implies$ symbol.

   Just as $=$ doesn't mean ‘outputs’,  $\implies$ doesn't mean ‘therefore’.